# ng-model is not getting updated using <textarea> of (angular-ui-tinymce)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tinymce

Trying to save the content entered in the text editor but the content is not getting set in the ng-model and I am unable to pass the
 ng-model data even to my controller.js file

HTML code:

```
    <form method="post">
    <textarea ui-tinymce ng-model="tinymceModel"></textarea>
    </form>
```

JS code:

```
    xyz:$scope.tinymceModel,
```

Comment: I got same problem, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController">
  <textarea ng-model="tinymceModel" ng-list="&#10;" ng-trim="false" rows="10"></textarea>
</body>
```

Controller

```
testApp.controller('testController', function ($scope)
{
    $scope.tinymceModel =
    [
      "First String",
      "Second String",
      "Third String"
    ];
});
```

```js
// Code goes here

var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

testApp.controller('testController', function ($scope)
{
    $scope.tinymceModel =
    [
      "First String",
      "Second String",
      "Third String"
    ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController">
  <textarea ng-model="tinymceModel" ng-list="&#10;" ng-trim="false" rows="10"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```